# How to get the Log File Viewer working in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to use the log file viewer in my install4j installation, and no matter what I do the text box is empty. The log file doesn't exist when the form is shown.  When the user clicks next, a batch executable runs that calls a java process and that creates and writes out to this log file.  I've successfully redirected stdout to a variable, and used the text display to show the updating variable contents but I can't get the log viewer to work for the actual log file.

I've tried several combinations of pointing to the file.  No errors are ever present in the installation log.

I've used

```
${installer:sys.installationDir}/logs/logfile.log
logs/logfile.log
c:\program files\my app\logs\logfile.log
```

Comment: I don't have this problem here. Can you send a complete test case to support@ej-technologies.com?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that relative files in the log file viewer form component were not resolved relative to the installation directory. This will be fixed in 8.0.3. In the meantime, you can prepend

${installer:sys.installationDir}/

to the "Log file" property or the "Log file viewer" form component, then it will work.